# C++ CMake cannot find Boost 1.63 (using CLion IDE)

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, cmake

I literally spent a good 6 hours on it and looked everywhere on the internet.

Here is what I have done. I am on Windows 10 using JetBrain CLion IDE. Directly downloaded MinGW 5.3, not through CodeBlocks. Downloaded Boost 1.63 and unzipped it. Ran `bootstrap.bat gcc` and `b2.exe toolset=gcc` to build it. During installation, `gcc-mingw-5.3.0` appeared tons of times so I suppose they are somehow linked now. Then a new folder `C:/Boost` appeared containing only two folders: include and lib.

Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(BoostTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Boost/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR C:/Boost/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(BoostTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Since the original directory (which I unzipped from the download) does not have directories named `include` and `lib`, I figured I should go with the directory created by installation(or building). Then I get this error:

```
CMake Error at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1169 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/Boost/include/boost/version.hpp" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Warning at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Warning at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Error at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1793 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 0.0.0

  Boost include path: C:/Boost/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Workspace_cpp/BoostTest/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

You see, CMake is somehow able to reach this `version.hpp` file, but cannot read it. I have seen quite a few people posting the same question, but none of their solutions worked for me. I have tried to set `INCLUDE_DIR` and `LIBRARY_DIR` to the original directory, and not helping a bit. I am truly frustrated. I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Update:
Thank you oLen for pointing it out! It was helpful. I have updated my CMakeList.txt to be:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/Boost)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/Boost/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/Boost/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

However, I am receiving a new error message:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Workspace_cpp\BoostTest
CMake Warning at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


CMake Error at D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion 2017.1/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1793 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
```

I think it successfully located the directory but could not process it. I am sorry for keep asking, these errors make absolutely no sense to me. May I also know if I should build Boost before using it, since in the official Boost Get Started page, it does not say to build it. The error message also wants me to `set BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR`. Could you please shed some more light? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a few days, installing and uninstalling tons of times, it turns out that I was just mistaking one line:

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/boost/include/boost-1_63)
```

That is it! Oh my GOD.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the variables to find Boost correctly.

If you take a look at [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake), you see the following:

> ```
> # This module reads hints about search locations from variables::
> #
> #   BOOST_ROOT             - Preferred installation prefix
> #    (or BOOSTROOT)
> #   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR       - Preferred include directory e.g. <prefix>/include
> #   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR       - Preferred library directory e.g. <prefix>/lib
> #   Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS  - Set to ON to disable searching in locations not
> #                            specified by these hint variables. Default is OFF.
> #   Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
> #                          - List of Boost versions not known to this module
> #                            (Boost install locations may contain the version)
> ```

In your case, the easiest solution is to set `BOOST_ROOT` to the folder containing `lib` and `include` (i.e. `C:/Boost`), or to use the correct variable names `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` (**without second underscore**).

The variables with the second underscore also exist, but they are *set* when you search for Boost.